# How to format a timestamp in android Webview using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to format a timestamp such as 1406270888 to Sunday, July 25, 2014 12:48:08 PM in a WebView on android device.

My Javascript code is as follows:

```
<script>
    var chatTimestamp=parseInt(1406270888);

    var date = new Date(chatTimestamp*1000);
    var localTime =date.toLocaleDateString()+ " "+ date.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = localTime;
</script>
```

But the output I get is as follows:

Sunday, July 25, 2014 12:48:08

So Basically AM PM is missing.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaletimestring.asp

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var chatTimestamp=parseInt(1406270888);

        var date = new Date(chatTimestamp*1000);

   document.write(date.toString());
   document.write(date.getFullYear()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getDate()+' '+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+':'+date.getSeconds());

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nha Td, But I tried it already doesn't work.
And the wierd thing is the same code that i put in the question puts AM PM on w3schools online compiler but behave's differently in WebView on android device.

Comment: i edit my code you can use date.toString() or date.getFullYear()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getDate()+' '+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+':'+date.getSeconds()

Comment: yes I tried it but still no AM or PM there.
I get in a format like Fri Jul 25 2014 12:18:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)2014-6-25 12:18:8

Comment: date.getHours() get hour from 0 to 23 so you don't need am or pm

Comment: Hmmm yeah right more over i can figure a way to convert 0 23 to 0 12 with AM and PM....thanks bro